# How to schedule airflow DAG to run over midnight UTC

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG which I want to run every hour between 10AM UTC till the next day 3AM UTC

I'm currently using the following schedule interval, but it does not seem to work:

```
schedule_interval='0 10-3/2 * * *',
```

By using the cron style interval, think I might have to split the intervals into two DAGS, eg. 10-23:59 UTC and 0-3 UTC

But not sure if there is a better solution for this scenario, any help would be great !

Comment: You could use the comma in your cron to include additional values, like 0 0-3,10-23 * * *

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly! Thanks - @MiguelTrejo